# In Selenium Webdriver, click button once the text is entered in text box

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to build a Selenium Automation framework for Gmail.
I have installed below tools:
JDK, Eclipse, Selenium Jars, Gradle, TestNG

I am trying to login to gmail. But i cam getting below error by the time i enter my username.
Its trying to click "Next" button before username is entered.

Can I use `wait` where ever required while developing framework?
Do I need to maintain any standards while calling `wait`.
Write any user defined `wait` methods.

Error:
FAILED: gmailLoginShouldBeSuccessful
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 207 milliseconds

My Code:

```
@Test
public void gmailLoginShouldBeSuccessful(){
    //1.Go to Gmail website
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Selenium_Softwares_Docs_Videos\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.1.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://gmail.com");     
    //2.Fill in username
    WebElement userTextBox = driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
    userTextBox.clear();
    userTextBox.sendKeys("xxxx");
    //3. click on next button
    WebElement nxtBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("next"));
    nxtBtn.click();
    //4.Fill in password
    WebElement pwdTextBox = driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd-hidden"));
    userTextBox.clear();
    userTextBox.sendKeys("xxxxxxx");
    //5.Click sign in
    WebElement signBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("signIn"));
    signBtn.click();        
}
```

Comment: you should use pwdTextBox instead of userTextBox when setting pasword

Comment: Hi, wait adjustment has been done extremely well in WATIR(Selenium wrapper), It checks exists?,visible?,enabled? writable? before it interact with any element, If it delays for any of these four ,it waits. Try it.

Comment: There's an API for gmail. Why not use it instead of automating the UI?

Comment: You can use Thread.sleep() after entering text. If this works then go ahead with some Explicit waits() and Visibility of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use explicit wait to achieve your requirement.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(yourWebDriver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//xpath_to_element")));
```

Webdriver will wait for 5 seconds for your element to be able to be clicked.

Comment: This may not have solved the problem. The clickable condition may be satisfied but the user name has not been entered yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome Driver instead of internet Explorer:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestCommons {
    @Test
    public void gmailLoginShouldBeSuccessful() throws InterruptedException {
        // 1.Go to Gmail website
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://gmail.com");
        // 2.Fill in username
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("vishala");
        // 3. click on next button
        driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
        // 4.Fill in password
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("vishala");
        // 5.Click sign in
        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Hope this will work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you send a RETURN key rather than click the Sign-In button?